# How to create a new record for every existing record and reference existing records to newly created records?

Tags: mysql

Here is my current database schema:

`category` table:

```
+------------+------------+
| id         | name       |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | category1  |
| 2          | category2  |
+------------+------------+
```

It is created in following way:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3889 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

I need to create super category record for every existing category record in following way:

- Add new self referencing not-nullable column `parent_id` (should reference to `id`)
- For new records (super categories) `parent_id` should be set to `id` of its own record
- For existing records (categories) `parent_id` should be set to `id` of newly created record.

**Expected result:**

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| id         | name       | parent_id  |   
+------------+------------+------------+
| 1          | category1  | 3          |
| 2          | category2  | 4          |
| 3          | category1  | 3          |
| 4          | category2  | 4          |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

The part I have difficulty with is setting `parent_id` for existing records pointed to `id` of new records.
Any ideas?

Comment: Generally this is not something which you should handle in SQL, the application code should do this..

Comment: This has to run only once, so idea is to do that as part of data / schema migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do a self join:

```
update category p
inner join category c
on c.name=p.name
set c.parent_id=p.id
where c.id<>p.id
```